# Heroku PG:ConnectionBad when running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I'm running `heroku run rails db:migrate -app my_app_name` and its failing to establish a connection.

Log:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_production
  url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

When I run `heroku config --app my_app_name` I can see that there is a `DATABASE_URL` so I am unsure why this error is occurring. I have tried other stack overflow answers but nothing appears to be working.

Please let me know if there is any further information required. A

Comment: You have a `DATABASE_URL` set but you're looking for `MY_APP_DATABASE_URL` in your configuration.

Comment: I'll let it close as a Typo. cheers